# Aspose OCR - Unable to read the text correctly

Tags: java, ocr, aspose

I tried to use the image below to extract its text contents using Aspose OCR library, unfortunately the result was not correct.

[image]

`OcrEngine.getText()` returns something like this:

```
run:
HEY: + it^7--+i-*l?/r]-*+\>/
m
^s^us^^stm?s^
M\-i-/!$~-
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 minute 38 seconds)
```

Here's my code:

```
import com.aspose.ocr.core.publicapi.*;
import com.aspose.ocr.core.publicapi.pal.PalFontFamily; 
import java.io.*;

public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        String imagePath = "hi.jpg";
        String etalonFile = "englishStandarts.xml";
        String fontFile = "arialAndTimesAndCourierRegular.xml";
        String resourcePath = "resources.zip";

        OcrEngine ocr = new OcrEngine(resourcePath, new int[] {4, 5, 6, 7 }, etalonFile, fontFile);
        ocr.getConfig().setNeedRotationCorrection(false);

        File image = new File(imagePath);
        ocr.setImage(image);

        ILanguage language = Language.load("english");
        ocr.getLanguages().addLanguage(language);

        try{
            if(ocr.process()){
                System.out.println("HEY: "+ocr.getText());
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be problem reading text from this image. Even the latest release does not work. Please report this issue in Aspose forums at http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.ocr-product-family/493/showforum.aspx.

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.